# Is there a way to open a file once I have verified it exists?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently with the VBA code below, I'm able to successfully verify if a file, with the name "Test", exists or not. If it exists, it returns the entire name of the file. However, what I am trying to do is open that file I found. So far, the forums I have searched for provide explanations on opening a workbook or an excel file, but I am trying to open any type of file (such as .docx, .pdf or .txt and etc.)

```vb
Sub findFile()

Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileExists As String

'name of the file I would like to find in C:\.
strFileName = "Test"
strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
 
   If strFileExists = "" Then
        MsgBox "The file doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "The file does exist"
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Check this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute

Comment: @Mike67 Thank you, I believe this is what I am looking for, I will take a look at this.

Comment: @Mike67 This has solved and answered my question. Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: FYI if you just use `Dir(fileName)` then it will look in the "current directory" - that might or might not be what you expect, so it's best to always use the full filepath and name when using Dir(), and not just the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just so the answer doesn't stay blank, I'm expanding on my comment.)

In VBA, to launch a file, use the `ShellExecute` function. You can use this to start an application (exe) directly or open a file (pdf\txt\doc) using the default handler.

Here is sample code to open a PDF file using the default PDF application.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\Files\Project_V1.pdf", "", "", "open", 1
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Documentation can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim strFile As String, strExist As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    strFile = "C:\Users\pppp\Desktop\xxx\xxx.xlsx"
    
    strExist = Dir(strFile)
    
    'Check if exist
    If strExist <> "" Then
        'Open file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    End If
    
    'Close file
    wb.Close
    
End Sub
```